# XSL How to calculate same node name?

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

I'm trying to find a way to compute the sum of same nodes in a parent node.

I have this XML code :

```
<course> 
  <user name="Jack"> 
    <ExerciceNote note="50" />
    <Information>The second exercice</Information>
    <ExerciceNote note="90" /> 
  </user> 
  <user name="Peter"> 
    <ExerciceNote note="60" /> 
    <ExerciceNote note="80" /> 
    <Information>The last exercice</Information>
    <ExerciceNote note="75" /> 
  </user> 
</course>
```

I want to calcultate the sum of each Exercice :

```
<xsl:template match="course">
  <html>
    <body>
      <p>Student name: <xsl:apply-templates select="user" />
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" /> </p>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="user">
  <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ExerciceNote" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ExerciceNote">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(???)" />
</xsl:template>
```

I try many things to replace the ???

I want a result like this :

```
Jack
total = 140
Peter
total = 215
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to iterate over the ExerciceNotes, you can stay on the "user level" to get the data you want. Or rather, `sum()` expects that you specify a group of elements with numeric contents, like the attribute `@note` values of the ExerciceNotes that are children of the currently selected user, instead of single values.

Try this XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"     
                              xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xsl:text>
    <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="user">
    <p><xsl:text>Student name: </xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </p>
    <p><xsl:text>total = </xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="sum(ExerciceNote/@note)"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand, I just need to stay on the node, and get the sum !, Great it works!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple template

a) Iterate on each user and then calculate sum

Help taken from [XML PlayGround](http://www.xmlplayground.com/iT4J53)

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="/course/user">
        <tr>

            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Total =
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(./ExerciceNote/@note)" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```